# Android posting tweet using twitter4j

Tags: android, post, share, twitter4j, status

I am using Twitter4j library to post my tweets to twitter. I can (from code) directly post tweets to twitter but I don't want this type. I want user to get the tweet share screen so that he can write whatever he like in the share textbox provided by twitter itself.

Currently I have done following;

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            AccessToken a = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

            twitter.updateStatus("Check this out");
```

This will post the tweet to twitter but it is done directly.

Thank you,

Comment: You need to create your own layout and then you can use the same code which you have wrote.

Comment: isn't there any way to get twitter's share-tweet screen like there has been in other apps ? creating our own layout might be seen otherwise at later times and plus it won't be official.

Comment: Try  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("/*");
            intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Thiws is a share message");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

Comment: i want twitter share page to appear directly without needing to select the application option.